# Is there a tool like Reflector for COM libraries?

Tags: com, reflector

Is there a tool like Reflector for COM libraries? I would like to open a COM library and browse the classes and interfaces just like in Reflector. I would rather not install Visual Basic 6.0 in order to do this, if possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not in the same way however there are number of tools that allow you to examine the type library.  For example [OleView](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=5233b70d-d9b2-4cb5-aeb6-45664be858b6&displaylang=en).

You can also get a good idea of the types inside COM library by simply adding it to a .NET project.  You can then use object browser to browser the resulting interop assembly or even use Reflector on the assembly.

Answer (score 3):

Even though normal reason for this tool is doing security assessment for COM objects you can still try ComRaider - http://labs.idefense.com/software/fuzzing.php#more_comraider

It's similar to Oleview.