# standard ActiveXObject reference list

Tags: windows, activex, javascript

Is there a reference for the standard available `ActiveXObject` objects? so far I know of:

- Excel.Application
- Excel.Sheet
- Scripting.FileSystemObject

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such thing as "standard" ActiveX/COM objects. The ProgIDs you listed belong to just a few of a great number of Windows and third-party software components that expose their functionality via COM.

If you just want to know what ProgIDs are registered on your computer, you can find a list under the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` registry key.

Comment: thanks, and then is the only way to get available methods to walk through each one and find any visible methods?

Comment: @Rixius: Take a look at the "OLE/COM Object viewer" from the Platform SDK.

Comment: There're many tools that allow you to browse COM classes and interfaces, e.g. Microsoft's [OleView](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=5233b70d-d9b2-4cb5-aeb6-45664be858b6). See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/780880/is-there-a-tool-like-reflector-for-com-libraries. Or do you want to do this programmatically?